# How to prevent highcharts smoothing my data?

Tags: highcharts

Highcharts/Highstocks does unnecessary smoothing of the data. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

[Here is the chart](https://codepen.io/chapkovski/full/GROEjvR) with the data. Raw data is [available here](https://blocke-channels-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/__temp_MC-EB-016_43512004_labeled.json).

The full chart is weirdly smoothed, like that:

[image]

And if I plot the same data in Python (`matplotlib`) it looks different:

[image]

And if I zoom in the corresponding part in Highcharts, it looks as it should:

[image]

**UPDATE:
apparently this smoothing happens only in HighStocks. In pure Highcharts the chart looks exactly as in Python: https://codepen.io/chapkovski/pen/mdqwOrO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is disabling [dataGrouping](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.dataGrouping)

```js
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dataGrouping: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    },
```

For the future please do not duplicate the same topic on multiple support channels (https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=48131)